# QGIS problem using join by location algorithm

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, qgis-modeler

I am new to QGIS.

I have a problem when i use the algorithm "Join by location" in my graphical modeler, it returns me the "uknown error". I think the problem is that the shape i´m using to join is empty, i mean it has not elements in it. But, i need to keep it empty because the algorithm i´m creating can be used in differents situation, maybe  in another study, it will has some elements.

If the shape doesn´t have features, i would want that the model just skip that step. I´m not good at writing in Python.

How do I solve this to adapt the process for every situation?

I don´t post all the model because is extensive, but the other parts are the same as the one in the picture.

[image: Graphical Modeler]

[image: >Atributte table]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Alejandrogarcia! I think a [custom](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) script would be required for this which would include writing some python code with an `if` statement to check if any features exist in the input shapefile. If so, run the algorithm otherwise do something else. This script would replace the join algorithm in your modeler. Could you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/298433/edit) your question to include more details such as a screenshot of your modeler and what do you want to happen if no features exist?

Comment: 1. Thanks for you reponse @Joseph, i prefer to not use python algorithm, because this model will be used by people that don´t know anything about python. 2. If the shape doesn´t have features, i want to skip that step, that´s all

Comment: @Alejandrogarcia As Joseph said, the only way do to that is using python to check if your layer have features. You can make a little script then import it in your model as a new box, this shouldn't confuse your users too much.

Comment: Ok!, @MaxPlank i will try creating a little script!, Thank you

Comment: @Alejandrogarcia Just comment back if you don't success I might help you

Comment: @MaxPlank i have find it using a diferent method. If i use de SAGA algorithm "add polygon attribute to points" the problem is solucionated because it skips that layer when attributes are null.